# How do I get the Xorg folder so I edit my mouse?

Tags: xorg, xubuntu, mouse

Okay so I'm new to Xubuntu and I'm trying to get rid of the mouse acceleration like windows has it but I've been told that I need to edit files in xorg first. But the folder is not there and I can't right-click and make it because of permissions. I've tried doing

```
sudo -X configure
```

but i get:

```
Fatal server error:
Server is already active for display 0
If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
and start again.
```

Is there anyway to get the folder back?

Answer (score -1):

Just simply kill Xorg server for this session? :)

`sudo xkill -a`

to start Xorg server after configuring Your mouse acceleration:

`sudo xinit`.

Comment: When i do sudo xkill -a it gives me a pointer with an X an wherever i click terminal says Aborting...

Comment: From the `xkill` man-page: Use of this option is highly discouraged.